# When creating a foreign key I am getting the error "Syntax error: missing 'closing parenthesis'

Tags: foreign-keys, syntax-error, mysql-workbench

I am using MySQL Workbench.
 
In the line:

```
REFERENCES section_t(section_id, semester, year)
```

I am getting the error

```
"Syntax error: missing 'closing parenthesis'".
```

The word 'semester' is underlined and is where the error is coming from.

I don't understand why MySQL is asking for a closing parenthesis here.I built several other foreign keys with multiple fields and those are working fine, but in this specific place I am getting an error. I thought maybe I was having a problem with a reserved word, but that does not seem to be the case. I also can't see where I have any parenthesis in the wrong place, or am missing one.

If any can help, it would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the SQL:

```
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema cphillips03
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema cphillips03
-- -----------------------------------------------------
USE `cphillips03` ;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `cphillips03`.`advisor_t` ;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `cphillips03`.`classroom_t` ;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `cphillips03`.`course_t` ;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `cphillips03`.`department_t` ;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `cphillips03`.`instructor_t` ;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `cphillips03`.`instructor_t` ;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `cphillips03`.`prereq_t` ;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `cphillips03`.`section_t` ;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `cphillips03`.`student_t` ;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `cphillips03`.`takes_t` ;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `cphillips03`.`teaches_t` ;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `cphillips03`.`timeslot_t` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `cphillips03`.`classroom_t`
-- -----------------------------------------------------


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cphillips03`.`classroom_t` (
  `building` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `room_number` VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `capacity` DECIMAL(4,0) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`building`, `room_number`))
;
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Insert commands for `cphillips03`.`classroom_t`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
insert into classroom_t values('Lamberton', 134, 10);

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `cphillips03`.`timeslot_t`
-- -----------------------------------------------------


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cphillips03`.`timeslot_t` (
  `timeslot_id` VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `day` VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `start_hr` TIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '00:00:00',
  `start_min` TIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '00:00:00',
  `end_hour` TIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_min` TIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`timeslot_id`, `day`, `start_hr`, `start_min`))
 ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `cphillips03`.`department_t`
-- -----------------------------------------------------


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cphillips03`.`department_t` (
  `dept_name` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `building` VARCHAR(15) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `budget` DECIMAL(12,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`dept_name`),
  FOREIGN KEY (building)
    REFERENCES classroom_t(building)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
    )
 ;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `cphillips03`.`course_t`
-- -----------------------------------------------------


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cphillips03`.`course_t` (
  `course_id` VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `title` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `dept_name` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `credits` DECIMAL(2,0) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`course_id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (dept_name)
    REFERENCES department_t(dept_name)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
    )
;




-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `cphillips03`.`instructor_t`
-- -----------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cphillips03`.`instructor_t` (
  `instructor_id` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `name` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `dept_name` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `salary` DECIMAL(8,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`instructor_id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (dept_name)
    REFERENCES department_t(dept_name)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
    )
 ;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `cphillips03`.`prereq_t`
-- -----------------------------------------------------


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cphillips03`.`prereq_t` (
  `course_id` VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `prereq_id` VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`course_id`, `prereq_id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (course_id)
    REFERENCES course_t(course_id)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
    )
 ;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `cphillips03`.`section_t`
-- -----------------------------------------------------


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cphillips03`.`section_t` (
  `course_id` VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `section_id` VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `semester` VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `year` DECIMAL(4,0) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `building` VARCHAR(15) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `room_number` VARCHAR(7) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `timeslot_id` VARCHAR(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`course_id`, `section_id`, `semester`, `year`),
  FOREIGN KEY (course_id)
    REFERENCES course_t(course_id)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (building, room_number)
    REFERENCES classroom_t(building, room_number)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (timeslot_id)
    REFERENCES timeslot_t(timeslot_id)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
    )
 ;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `cphillips03`.`student_t`
-- -----------------------------------------------------


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cphillips03`.`student_t` (
  `student_id` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `name` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `dept_name` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `tot_cred` DECIMAL(3,0) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`student_id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (dept_name)
    REFERENCES department_t(dept_name)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
    )
 ;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `cphillips03`.`takes_t`
-- -----------------------------------------------------


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cphillips03`.`takes_t` (
  `takes_id` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `course_id` VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `sec_id` VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `semester` VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `year` DECIMAL(4,0) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `grade` VARCHAR(2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`takes_id`, `course_id`, `sec_id`, `semester`, `year`),
  FOREIGN KEY (course_id)
    REFERENCES course_t(course_id)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (sec_id, semester, year)
    REFERENCES section_t(section_id, semester, year)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
    )
;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `cphillips03`.`teaches_t`
-- -----------------------------------------------------


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cphillips03`.`teaches_t` (
  `teaches_id` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `course_id` VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `sec_id` VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `semester` VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `year` DECIMAL(4,0) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`teaches_id`, `course_id`, `sec_id`, `semester`, `year`),
  FOREIGN KEY (course_id)
    REFERENCES course_t(course_id)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
    )
 ;



-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `cphillips03`.`advisor_t`
-- -----------------------------------------------------


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cphillips03`.`advisor_t` (
  `student_id` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `instructor_id` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`student_id`, `instructor_id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (student_id)
    REFERENCES student_t(student_id)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (instructor_id)
    REFERENCES instructor_t(instructor_id)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
    )
 ;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Comment: Are you sure you posted the same code you tried?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Isaiah. I copied the text from the query window and pasted it as is. I need to identify this foreign key in two places, and have re-written it from scratch multiple times to make sure I don't have a type-o or missing parenthesis. This is indeed the actual text. Let me know if I can provide any additional clarification.

Comment: Show me your course_t and section_t table definitions, so I can test this on my end.

Comment: Everything upto and including the primary key is good (including the last few lines), so its specific to the foreign keys.....

Comment: Isaiah, I think you are exactly right. I think I have defined a primary key wrong somewhere and then defined a foreign key in the wrong table. I am trying to figure out if the 'semester' field needs to be defined as primary in a different table (like takes_t perhaps) and then referenced as a foreign key in one of the other tables? Again, I really appreciate the time you are taking to assist men.

Comment: Your error is rather cryptic -- if things dont match up, you should get an error for cannot set foreign key constraint

Comment: I am not figuring this out. I must have some larger issue in the entire script or my understanding of the assignment. I will just skip this for now and ask the instructor this week. Thank you for your efforts.

Comment: Are you running each query separately, or in one huge batch. If its the latter, post the **entire** script.

Comment: Thank you. The entire script is uploaded now.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've finally found the source problem; Use the more probably solution and ignore the less-likely one.

Comment: You have put in a lot of work on this. Thank you! The difference between section_id in one place and sec_id in another place is something I brought to the instructor's attention. The schema is pre-built on the server and he plans to fix this for the next class, but for our class we have to keep this the same. Also, I cannot remove course_id from the primary key because the instructor has set the PK's. Based on your input, would adding an index fix this problem?

Comment: Maybe if you do something like `ADD INDEX( section_id, semester, year )` If you're satisfied with an answer (or in this case, the amount of work going into finding a solution), you can accept answers here at Stackoverflow. Later, you'll be able to vote up good posts when you have a little more rep. I am glad to have helped you.

Comment: Success! I used the following query (not sure if your instructor will let you though): `ALTER TABLE section_t ADD INDEX( section_id, semester, year )` and then ran`takes_t`'s `CREATE TABLE` query

Comment: Yep, that did it! I rewrote it a little bit. Rather than using ADD INDEX after the table is built, I just added the index to section_t while building the table. Now I can add the foreign keys for both takes_t and teaches_t and the script runs without errors. Thank you so much! You have been a HUGE help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Main Solution

EDIT: **After a large amount of discussion, we have determined that adding an index is the best solution to this problem:**

```
ALTER TABLE section_t
ADD INDEX( section_id, semester, year )
```

OR

```
CREATE TABLE section_t (
...
INDEX( section_id, semester, year )
```

### Past Discussion for history

Well, I am getting no errors; are you sufre you are using the most up-to-date version of mysql?

Code Ran:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS takes_t (
takes_id VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
course_id VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
sec_id VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
semester VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
year DECIMAL(4, 0) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
grade VARCHAR(2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY( takes_id, course_id, sec_id, semester, year ),
FOREIGN KEY(course_id)
REFERENCES course_t(course_id)
ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY( sec_id, semester, year )
REFERENCES section_t( section_id, semester, year )
ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
ENGINE = INNODB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=utf8;
```

I get the following response:

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected
```

Tell me if you spot anything.

EDIT: With your full script, I'm getting the following error when doing takes_t. I have entered all queries individually:

```
ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

I get it when I at the following line:

```
FOREIGN KEY(sec_id, semester, year)
REFERENCES section_t( section_id, semester, year )
```

Possible (though unlikely) solution: Replace all instances of sec_id with section_id

**More likely solution: Remove course_id from section_t's primary key**

*Reason: Foreign keys need an index; the primary key's index might only apply when the full primary key is used.*

Comment: Or, you could remove all the backticks

Comment: Thank you for your input. I added the backticks and got the same error. I also tried removing all the backticks, but I am still getting the same error on the word 'semester'.

Comment: Same place? Why not remove all the backticks? You don't have to backtick quote column names unless there is a space.

Comment: You are fast!  =) I edited my reply to say I also removed the backticks and got the same result. I appreciate your efforts. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried what I just posted / Edited yet? Also, I'm typing this directly in the mysql command line program.

Comment: It is so weird, Isaiah. I copied the script you sent, and I still get the error. I am using a Mac, so I thought maybe there was a problem specific to the OS. I switched over to Windows, loaded the latest version of MySQL Workbench for Windows, ran the query again, and I am still getting the same results. I can post the entire script if you want, but I don't want to take advantage of your generosity. I am just not sure what else to do. I know I must be overlooking something extremely obvious.

Comment: Yeah, post the entire script…………… Also, what version mysql are you using and did you try it in the command line?